# Checking sensors in an environment

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have the following diagram (did this only to ask here, it's obviously missing details):

[image: CLass Diagram]

From the diagram you can see I have to check if all sensors in an environment are respecting the established conditions, but I'm not comfortable with the way I'm implementing this...

```
class Environ:

    def __init__(self):
        self.load_conditions()
        self.load_modules()

    def load_modules(self):
        self.modules = []
        # Don't like this!
        m = Module(self.conditions)
        self.modules.append(m) 

    def run_modules(self):
        for m in self.modules:
             m.process_sensors()

class Module:

    def __init__(self, conditions):
        self.conditions = conditions
        self.load_all_sensors()

    def load_all_sensors(self):
        self.sensors = []
        # Don't like this!
        s = Sensor(self.conditions)
        self.modules.append(m) 


      def process_sensors(self):
         for s in sensors:
             if not s.is_sensor_respecting_conditions():
                 raise ...

e = Environ()
e.run_modules()
```

My question is: do I really have to replicate all these conditions? What can I do to make this code more clean?

Comment: It the part you dislike that all three classes store the conditions, instead of just `Environ`? Do the other two know their environment, so they can use its conditions?

Comment: Yes, I think the conditions should be shared among Environ, Module and Sensor without having to pass as a parameter. And no, they don't know their environment.

Comment: This is not the original title. "Checking sensors in an environment" says nothing about this question.

Comment: @LuizFernando: I've changed it as titles here should state the purpose of the code (the review request should just remain in the post).  If this is not an accurate description, you may fix it yourself.

Comment: Would it be difficult to pass the environment (or the conditions, if that's the only relevant part) as a parameter to all the operations that need it, as Sean suggested?

Answer (score 1):

The idea with objects is they maintain the data that they own. Try to avoid having the object hold onto other data just because it uses it. This makes later refactoring harder.
Below is a sketch of what the `process` chain might look like.

```
class Sensor(object):
    def process(self, conditions):
        if not self.is_respecting_conditions(conditions):
            raise Exception("Fill me in properly")

        self.apply(conditions)

class Module(object):
    def process(self):
        for s in self.sensors:
            try:
                s.process(self.conditions)
            except:  # Handle actual exception here
                pass  # whatever work is needed

class Environment(object):
    def process(self):
        for m in self.modules:
            m.process()
```

This assumes that the conditions are per module. If they are per `Environment` then you could would add the condition parameter to the `process` method of the `Module` object.